# multithreaded multiclient programming

Tags: java, multithreading

I am doing a client - server application.
I want to connect multiple clients with a single server. Here each client is connected with the server using three ports:

- First - sending an image
- Second - sending the keyboard events
- Third - sending mouse events

All these informations are sent to server, but it is creating problem in multithreading. If I use single thread, then it is ok, but in the case of multithread it creates problem due to the multiple ports.
Please can anyone give me the solution.

thanks

**client code:**

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.awt.Robot.*;
    class Client extends JFrame
    {
        //  port no 143 for sending images...
        //  port no 321 for recieving mouseEvents...
        //  port no 678 for recieving keyEvents...

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            new Client();
        }

    /*-----------------------------for Establish Connection------------------*/
        Client()
        {
            super("10.1.8.123");

            setTitle("10.1.8.123");
            System.out.println("waiting for permission..");
            try
            {
                ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(112);
                Socket socket=s.accept();

                Thread.sleep(0,1);

            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {}

            setVisible(false);

            new ImageSender();
            new MouseEventsReceiver();
            new KeyboardEventsReceiver();
        }
    }
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    class ImageSender implements Runnable
    {       

        ImageSender()
        {
            Thread t=new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }

    /*----------------------------------For capture the screen-------------------*/
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Robot r=new Robot();
                Toolkit t=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                Rectangle rect=new Rectangle(t.getScreenSize());
                while(true)
                {
                    Socket s=new Socket("10.1.8.107",112);          
                    OutputStream out=s.getOutputStream();
                    ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(out);
                    BufferedImage b_img=r.createScreenCapture(rect);
                    ImageIcon img=new ImageIcon(b_img);
                    oos.writeObject(img);

                    Thread.sleep(100);

                    oos.close();    
                    out.close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("in ImageSender:"+e);
            }
        }
    }
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/   

    class MouseEventsReceiver implements Runnable
    {
        MouseEventsReceiver()
        {
            Thread t=new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("inside run....");

            try
            {
                ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(113);   //must be outside while()...            
                Robot r=new Robot();
                while(true)
                {
                    System.out.println("Socket created at port 321");
                //  ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(321);

                    Socket client=s.accept();
                    System.out.println("after accept...");

                    InputStream in=client.getInputStream();
                    ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(in);

                    MouseEvents m=(MouseEvents)ois.readObject();
                    System.out.println("Mouse Event Received X="+m.getX());

                    System.out.println("button:="+m.getButton());

                    r.mouseMove(m.getX(),m.getY());
                    if(m.getButton()==1)
                    {
                        r.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                        r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

                    }
                    else if(m.getButton()==2)
                    {
                        r.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK);
                        r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK);
                    }
                    else if(m.getButton()==3)
                    {
                        r.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
                        r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
                    }
                    else            
                    {
                    }           

                    ois.close();
                    in.close();
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("in mouseEvent Reciever:"+e);
            }
        }
    }
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    class KeyboardEventsReceiver implements Runnable
    {
        KeyboardEventsReceiver()
        {
            Thread t=new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("in keyboard run...");

            try
            {
                Robot r=new Robot();
                ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(114);   //must be outside while()...        

                while(true)
                {
                //  ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(678);           

                    Socket client=s.accept();
                    InputStream in=client.getInputStream();
                    ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(in);
                    KeyboardEvents k=(KeyboardEvents)ois.readObject();
                    System.out.println("Key Received:"+k.getKeyChar());
                    r.keyPress((char)k.getKeyChar());
                //  r.keyPress(97);

                    ois.close();
                    in.close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("inside Key board events.."+e);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**server code:**

```
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JMenu;
    import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
    import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
    import javax.swing.UIManager;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;


    public class Menu extends JFrame 
    {
        public String ip1="10.1.8.106";
        public String ip2="10.1.8.108";
        public String ip3="10.1.8.109";
        public int port=111;
        public int i;


        public Menu() 
        {

            setTitle("Server");

            JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

            JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
            file.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);

            JMenuItem client1 = new JMenuItem("clt1");
            JMenuItem client2 = new JMenuItem("clt2");
            JMenuItem client3 = new JMenuItem("clt3");

            client1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F1);
            client2.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F2);
            client3.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F3);

            client1.setToolTipText("Client1 selected");
            client2.setToolTipText("Client2 selected");
            client3.setToolTipText("Client3 selected");

            client1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
                {
                        new Screen(ip1,port);
                }
            });

                client2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
                {
                //  port=port+3;
                    new Screen(ip2,port+3);
                }
            });

                client3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
                {
                //  port=port+3;
                    new Screen(ip3,port+6);
                }
            });


            file.add(client1);
            file.add(client2);
            file.add(client3);

            menubar.add(file);

            setJMenuBar(menubar);

            setSize(250, 200);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {

            new Menu();

        }
    }
    class Screen extends JFrame
    {
        //  port no 143 for receiving images...
        //  port no 321 for sending mouseEvent...
        //  port no 678 for sending keyEvents...

        final JFrame frame;

    /*  public static void main(String args[])
        {
            new Screen();
        }*/
        Screen(String ip,int port)
        {
            super("Remote Access Server");
            frame=this;
            try
            {
            //  port=port+1;
                Socket s=new Socket(ip,port+1);

                Thread.sleep(0,1);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {}
            new ImageReceiver(frame,ip,port);

            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    class ImageReceiver extends Window implements Runnable,MouseListener,MouseMotionListener,KeyListener
    {
            String ipadd;
            int port1;
        ImageReceiver(Frame f,String ip,int port)
        {
            super(f);
            ipadd=ip;
            port1=port;
            addMouseListener(this);
            addMouseMotionListener(this);   //f not reqrd bcoz its done on window...
            f.addKeyListener(this);     //f is required for clicking on frames....

            f.requestFocus();   // must required ...

            Toolkit toolkit=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            setSize(toolkit.getScreenSize());

            setVisible(true);

            Thread t=new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(port1+1);
                while(true)
                {
                    Socket socket=s.accept();
                    setBackground(Color.black);
                    InputStream in=socket.getInputStream();
                    ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(in);
                    ImageIcon img=(ImageIcon)ois.readObject();
                    Graphics g=getGraphics();
                    img.paintIcon(this,g,0,0);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        /*--------------------------mouse events...----------------------------------------*/
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m)
        {
            System.out.println("mouse clicked");
            sendPacket(new MouseEvents(m.getX(),m.getY(),m.getButton()));
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m)
        {
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m)
        {
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent m)
        {
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent m)
        {
        }
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent m)
        {
            sendPacket(new MouseEvents(m.getX(),m.getY()));

        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent m)
        {
    //      sendPacket(new MouseEvents(m.getX(),m.getY(),m.getButton()));
        }

        private void sendPacket(MouseEvents m)
        {
            try
            {
            //  port1=port1+1;
                Socket s=new Socket(ipadd,port1+2);
                OutputStream out=s.getOutputStream(); 
                ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(out);
                oos.writeObject(m);
                oos.close();
                s.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        /*---------------------------keyboard events...-----------------------------------------------*/
        //all the events are required to be included.....+requestFocus() is also must...    

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k)
        {
            System.out.println("after key pressed...");
            sendKeyPacket(new KeyboardEvents(k.getKeyCode()));      
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k)
        {
            System.out.println("after key released...");
            sendKeyPacket(new KeyboardEvents(k.getKeyCode()));

        }
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k)
        {
            System.out.println("after key typed..."+k.getKeyChar());
            sendKeyPacket(new KeyboardEvents(k.getKeyChar()));

        }


        private void sendKeyPacket(KeyboardEvents k)
        {
            try
            {
            //  port1=port1+1;
                Socket s=new Socket(ipadd,port1+3);
                OutputStream out=s.getOutputStream(); 
                ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(out);
                oos.writeObject(k);
                oos.close();
                s.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Where is the multithreaded code here? :-)

Answer (score 0):

We'll need more to go on than just this:

```
case of multithread it creates problem due to the multiple ports
```

Exactly what problem do you see?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use UDP and TCP as a different connection and maintain this for socket connection...

if u maintain both UDP and TCP connection then it is easy for sending packet and make socket connection over port ..

you are in right way but you need to modify minor changes...gud keep it up this is ur way is ri8

And one more thing , if u are going to use multithreading then you have to quite good knowledge of thread management and synchronization..